# Js file not working properly in webview inside pager in jetpack compose

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a quiz app in jetpack compose. I have a webview inside a horizontal pager to display an html file which takes data from a list. The webview loads the same html file but for each pager page the data are different. When i run the app pager loads well all the data from the list. That means the js function for loading data works well. But when i try to checkAnswers it seems that JS file keeps the answer from 1st page and not refresh for the next.

```
ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        val (title, pager, navigation) = createRefs()
        val topGuideline = createGuidelineFromTop(.3f)

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 4.dp, start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp)
                .constrainAs(title) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                },
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 6.dp
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color.White
            )
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "Ερώτηση ${pagerState.currentPage + 1} από ${pagerState.pageCount}",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium.fontSize
            )
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(pager) {
                    top.linkTo(title.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(navigation.top)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                },
            userScrollEnabled = true
        ) { page ->

            Card(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 4.dp, start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        val pageOffset = (
                                (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState
                                    .currentPageOffsetFraction
                                ).absoluteValue
                        alpha = lerp(
                            start = 0.5f,
                            stop = 1f,
                            fraction = 1f - pageOffset.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                        )
                    },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
            ) {

                if (questionList is RequestState.Success) {
                    val questions = (questionList as RequestState.Success<List<Question>>).data
                    if (questions.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val question = questions[page]
                        jsInterface = JSInterface(context)
                        if (question.questionImage == null || question.questionImage == "") jsInterface!!.image =
                            "" else jsInterface!!.image =
                            question.questionImage
                        jsInterface!!.question = question.questionText
                        jsInterface!!.answer1 = question.answerA
                        jsInterface!!.answer2 = question.answerB
                        jsInterface!!.answer3 = question.answerC
                        jsInterface!!.answer4 = question.answerD
                        jsInterface!!.correctAnswer = question.correctAnswer

                        AndroidView(
                            factory = { context ->

                                WebView(context).apply {

                                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                                    )

                                    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                                        override fun onPageStarted(
                                            view: WebView?,
                                            url: String?,
                                            favicon: Bitmap?
                                        ) {
                                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                                            viewModel.dialogLoading(true)
                                        }

                                        override fun onPageFinished(
                                            view: WebView?,
                                            url: String?
                                        ) {
                                            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                                            viewModel.dialogLoading(false)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                                    addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface!!, "Android")
                                    setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                                    loadUrl(multipleChoiceFile)
                                }.also { webView = it }
                            },
                            update = {
                                it.loadUrl(multipleChoiceFile)
                                webView = it
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    else {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "No questions!")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(4.dp)
                .constrainAs(navigation) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
        ) {
            Button(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                onClick = {
                    if (viewModel.questionAnswered.value) {
                        scope.launch {
                            if (pagerState.currentPage == pagerState.pageCount - 1) {
                                viewModel.onEvent(QuizScreenEvent.OnEndClick)
                            } else {
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage +1)
                                viewModel.setQuestionAnswered(false)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        scope.launch {
                            webView?.evaluateJavascript("checkAnswers();", null)
                            viewModel.setQuestionAnswered(true)
                            delay(3000)
                        }

                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = if (viewModel.questionAnswered.value) {
                        if (pagerState.currentPage + 1 == pagerState.pageCount) "Τέλος" else "Επόμενο"
                    } else {
                        "Καταχώρηση"
                    },
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

the JSInterface

```
    class JSInterface(val context: Context) {
@get:JavascriptInterface
var question: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var answer1: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var answer2: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var answer3: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var answer4: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var answer5: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var correctAnswer: String? = null

@get:JavascriptInterface
var image: String? = null

@JavascriptInterface
fun multipleChoiceResult(toast: String) {
    getResult(context, toast)
}
```

and the css file

```
function getQuestionsAndAnswers() {

var myImage = Android.getImage();

var answers = [Android.getAnswer1().substring(2), Android.getAnswer2().substring(2),
Android.getAnswer3().substring(2), Android.getAnswer4().substring(2)];

var ids = [Android.getAnswer1().substring(0,1), Android.getAnswer2().substring(0,1),
    Android.getAnswer3().substring(0,1), Android.getAnswer4().substring(0,1)];

if (myImage === "") $("#image").css("display", "none");
else $("#image").attr("src", myImage);

$("#question").html(Android.getQuestion());

$("#1").text(answers[0]);
$("#2").text(answers[1]);
$("#3").text(answers[2]);
$("#4").text(answers[3]);}



function checkAnswers() {
$(".selected").removeClass("selected")
$(".right").removeClass("right")
$(".wrong").removeClass("wrong")

const targetText = Android.getCorrectAnswer();

var result = false

   $("span").each(function (i, item) {

       const isChecked = $(this).prev("input[type='radio']").prop("checked");
       const textCompare = $(this).attr('id').toString() === targetText;

       if (isChecked && textCompare) {
           $(this).closest("label").addClass(["selected", "right"]);
           result = true
       } else if (textCompare) {
           if (!isChecked) {
               $(this).closest("label").addClass(["selected", "right"]);
           }
       } else if (isChecked) {
           if (!textCompare) {
               $(this).closest("label").addClass(["selected", "wrong"]);
           }
       }
   });

   $('#overlay').css('display', 'flex');
   Android.multipleChoiceResult(result)}
```

Can someone give me a little help?